# Gtar in Solaris, tar to multiple splits based on size

Tags: unix, tar, solaris-10

I am using a gtar command  that should create the file of 10 GB in pendrive. I researched on it little bit and got to know that FAT 32 file system supports file of size 4gb max. How can I put check in middle of running gtar command that creates multiple files by splitting based on file size less than 4gb.

Gtar should be able to detect if file it creating is exceeding 4 GB size and then it should stop creating that file and continue creating the other one.

I know that we can make 10 GB file at one location and split that static file, but we do not want this.

Comment: Your question belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: [`man split`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5165/split-1.html#scrolltoc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` command like this:

```
cd /path/to/flash
tar cvf - /path/of/source/files |split -b 4198400
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the man page for these options.

```
[--tape-length=NUMBER] [--multi-volume] 


Device selection and switching:
-f, --file=ARCHIVE
use archive file or device ARCHIVE
--force-local
archive file is local even if it has a colon
-F, --info-script=NAME, --new-volume-script=NAME
run script at end of each tape (implies -M)
-L, --tape-length=NUMBER
change tape after writing NUMBER x 1024 bytes
-M, --multi-volume
create/list/extract multi-volume archive
--rmt-command=COMMAND
use given rmt COMMAND instead of rmt
--rsh-command=COMMAND
use remote COMMAND instead of rsh
--volno-file=FILE
use/update the volume number in FILE
Device blocking:
-b, --blocking-factor=BLOCKS

BLOCKS x 512 bytes per record
-B, --read-full-records
reblock as we read (for 4.2BSD pipes)
-i, --ignore-zeros
ignore zeroed blocks in archive (means EOF)
--record-size=NUMBER
NUMBER of bytes per record, multiple of 512
```

Comment: *Check the man page for these options.*  And do **what** with them?